# Padding Fields With White Space

Tags: t-sql

I have the following piece of code in my SELECT statement -

**`SELECT convert(varchar (24),ra.Reference)`**

If a result is  - R0_2, so 4 characters, how do you go about padding the trailing space (to the right) with the remaining 20 characters to make up 24?

Similar in that if I have a figure of say 18.00 what I want is to add a # to the front, which I know I can achieve with a CONCAT. 
However this field I want to be 16 characters and any leading space to be filled with white space, so this example would look like - 
'xxxxxxxxxx#18.00' (where x is a blank space)

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick you can use is to just concatenate to the string an amount of padding which is guaranteed to fill the missing spaces.  For the case of a string 24 characters long, in your first example, we can concatenate 24 spaces to the end of that string.  Then, take the first 24 characters from the left, and the resulting string should be *right* padded by spaces.  Similar logic applies to the other case.

**First query:**

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(24), ra.Reference) + '                        ', 24)
FROM yourTable
```

**Second query:**

```
SELECT RIGHT('               ' + '#' + CONVERT(varchar(16), ra.TotalValue), 16)
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: You my friend are a star.The second I modified slightly to RIGHT('               ' + '#' + convert(varchar (16),rac.TotalValue), 16)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't help it feel bad for Bill :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `REPLICATE` to accurately pad based on the length of text for each cell to ensure it's always 24 characters:

```
DECLARE @Test1 VARCHAR(24) = 'Test', 
        @Test2 VARCHAR(24) = 'Longer String'

SELECT CONCAT(@Test1, REPLICATE(N' ', 24 - LEN(@Test1))), 
       CONCAT(@Test2, REPLICATE(N' ', 24 - LEN(@Test2)))
```

And for the #....

```
DECLARE @Number DECIMAL(4,2) = 18.00
SELECT CONCAT(REPLICATE(' ', 15 - LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @Number))), '#',@Number)
```

I used 15 here despite it being 16 characters to account for the addition of the #